# Struggling with python generator function

Tags: python, generator

I've checked out several yield examples, but I cannot figure out how I'm supposed to use it in my task.

I have to make a generator function which has to give back one word read from file when called (and then get the next one and so on).

```
- Pass file path to the function
- Read in word char by char and assign it to a variable
- ........ yield word
```

The only thing I want to know is, how could I get the generator function to yield one word and then know which is the next word. I'm not looking for ready-made solutions, I'd like to understand what's going on.

Comment: Show us the code you have tried and describe what it *should* do and what it *actually* does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your generator function would work exactly like a non-generator function that adds those words to a list. Except instead of adding them to a list, you yield the word.

So a function that adds them to a list would be:

```
def per_word(filename):
    result = []

    with open(filename) as fh:
        for line in fh:
            for word in line.split():
                result.append(word)

    return result
```

The generator function simply yields instead:

```
def per_word(filename):
    with open(filename) as fh:
        for line in fh:
            for word in line.split():
                yield word
```

Comment: As an additional note, in Python 3.3+ you can replace that inner loop with `yield from line.split()`.

Comment: The problem is that it is said I have to read the file char by char. This part makes me not understand how could I yield a word that is formed with characters read in.

Comment: @swenn: but that is entirely separate from how generator functions work!  Figure out how to form words in a loop, to the point you can append them to a list and then you can make it a generator too.

Comment: @swenn: so just loop character by character, collecting them in a list or string, and every time you find whitespace or a punctuation mark you have found a word. Yield the collected characters, clear your collection data and continue your loop